# Issue in JPA Cascade Save with EmbeddedId in child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, embeddable

I am having three class. `Person`,`vehicle` and a `association` class to link the person and vehicle

**Person**

```
package entity;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Entity
@Table(name ="PERSON")
public class Person {
@EmbeddedId
private PKperson pkPerson;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="person")
private Set<PersonVehAssnVO> personVehAssnVOSet=new HashSet<PersonVehAssnVO>();

//getters & setters
}
```

**PKperson**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class PKperson implements Serializable {

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column(name="DOB_DT", nullable=false)
private Date dobDt;
}
```

**Vehicle**

```
package entity;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Entity
@Table(name ="VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {
@Id
@Column(name="VEHICLE_ID",unique=true, nullable=false)  
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_name")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "seq_name", sequenceName = "SEQ_VEHICLE_ID")
private Long vehicleId;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="vehicle")
private Set<PersonVehAssnVO> personVehAssnVOSet=new HashSet<PersonVehAssnVO>();

private String vehicleName;

//getters & setters
}
```

**Person Vehicle Association**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Entity
@Table(name ="PERSON_VEHICLE_ASSOC")
public class PersonVehAssnVO {
@EmbeddedId
private PKperson pkPerson;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "pkPerson.name",referencedColumnName ="NAME"),
@JoinColumn(name = "pkPerson.dobDt",referencedColumnName ="DOB_DT")})
private Person person;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "VEHICLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "VEHICLE_ID")
private Vehicle vehicle;

//getters & setters
}


//**Save Method**
PKperson pkPerson = new PKperson();
SimpleDateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = dtFormat.parse("1984-12-14");
pkPerson.setName("Magesh");
pkPerson.setDobDt(date1);

Person person = new Person();
person.setPKperson(pkPerson);

Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.setName("Honda350");

PersonVehAssnVO perVehAssnVO = new PersonVehAssnVO();
PersonVehAssnVO.setPKperson(pkPerson);
PersonVehAssnVO.setVehicle(vehicle);

Set<PersonVehAssnVO>  assocSet = new HashSet<PersonVehAssnVO>();
assocSet.add(PersonVehAssnVO);

person.setpersonVehAssnVOSet(assocSet);
vehicle.setpersonVehAssnVOSet(assocSet);

Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

transaction.begin();    
session.save(person);       
transaction.commit();
```

//=============================================================

While Executing the above save logic I am getting error ": `[entity.PersonVehAssnVO#component[name,dobDt]{dobDt=magesh, dobDt=1984-12-14 00:00:00}]"`

Show Sql Gives "`select personVehAssnVO_.NAME, personVehAssnVO_.DOB_DT, personVehAssnVO_.VEHICLE_ID as vehicle_34 from PERSON_VEHICLE_ASSOC where personVehAssnVO_.NAME=? and personVehAssnVO_.DOB_DT=?`"

I want to save `Person`,`Vehicle` and `association` in a single save means `CASCADE ALL` When I save `Person`.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Mark the date in PKPerson with the `@Temporal` annotation:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name="DOB_DT", nullable=false, length = 8)
private Date dobDt;
```

According to [the Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html)

> This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties
>   of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. It may only be
>   specified for fields or properties of these types.
>
> The Temporal annotation may be used in conjunction with the Basic
>   annotation, the Id annotation, or the ElementCollection annotation
>   (when the element collection value is of such a temporal type.

And according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473952/absence-of-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate):

> In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined.
>   When dealing with temporal data you might want to describe the
>   expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, or both). Use
>   the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that.

I hope this solves your problem. You can interchange the `TemporalType` with others that match your field type in the database. The column length also can be changed accordingly.

**Edit**

I think you also need to remove the `mappedBy="person"` and `mappedBy="vehicle"` from the annotation of the `PersonVehAssnVO` sets in the Person and Vehicle classes and replace them with full column properties so that these classes can be the owners of the relationship. Otherwise when you save a person, it will ignore updating any properties marked with the `mappedby` annotation because this means the Person is not the owner of that relationship.

Comment: I have tried it. No Luck. Correct me if I am wrong the error says there is no person(magesh,1984-12-14) to insert in association. Is hibernate expecting person should be saved before mapping it with Association?

Comment: I think you need to remove the mapped by from the annotation of the `PersonVehAssnVO` sets in the Person and Vehicle classes and replace it with full column properties so that these classes can be the owners of the relationship. Otherwise when you save a person, it will ignore updating any properties marked with the mappedby annotation because this means the Person is not the owner of that relationship